# CouchDB: Good document ids to lower storage requirements

Tags: database, hash, nosql, couchdb, b-tree

So I did some research and apparently the storage requirements can increase significantly with key size.

In reality I want to be able to use a "long int" as my key but this won't be possible as couchdb requires that keys are strings correct ? Is there any way to circumvent this ?

Because my ids look like:

```
{ "_id" : "10209939", ....data here ... }
{ "_id" : "10209940", ....data here ... }
{ "_id" : "10209941", ....data here ... }
```

I would like to keep them numerical to do range queries. But since the storage increases along with key length, my storage will explode. In a sense, these ids represented as strings take many more bytes that they would should they be interpreted as long ints.

Has anybody had experience storing documents with a "numerical" integer as ids ? How did you get good storage efficiency given that couchdb understands "_id" as being a string ? Can we tell it, no it's a "long int" not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id must be a string.  No alternative.

You can do range queries, but only a lexical range - not a numeric range.

Comment: And what characters are allowed for the ID ? Sorry but I cannot find it in the documentation ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any restrictions, just that you needs to URL encode it so it makes sense to use fairly standard ASCII to make it easier on your developers.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your document size is *very* small the id will not be significant. I suggest you do some testing and confirm how much space is actually lost between the different approaches. Don't forget to compact before doing your tests, and bear in mind that using CouchDB 1.2.0 data compression is also enabled, so the impact of large ids will be reduced also.

The strict requirement is JSON UTF-8 more details in the RFC http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt. You should ensure that, where possible, you are inserting documents with a sequential increasing id, as this reduces the b-tree's need to rebalance. You can also address this later by using compaction of course.

In most cases, the most sensible thing to use for your id is a meaningful value where you require uniqueness. CouchDB only enforces uniqueness on the id, so you might as well make it count!